# Anyone know how to change from the tcp protocol to the http one

Tags: python, sockets, http, server, client

I would like to know if anyone was able to change this code so that instead of it running on a wifi network it ran on http. I did all i could but i do not think there are any tutorials on how to preform this changing.

Server:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
port = 1234

server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(5)

run = True
client, addr = server.accept()
print('Got connection from',addr)

while run:
    try:
        data = input('>>>')

        client.send(data.encode('UTF-8'))

        msg = client.recv(1024)
        print(msg.decode('UTF-8'))
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print('Client lost server connection')
        print('Trying to connect . . .')
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print('Got connection from',addr)
```

Client:

```
import socket
import os
server = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1234

run = True
server.connect((host,port))
while run:


    msg = server.recv(1024)
    os.popen(msg.decode('UTF-8'))

    server.send('Client online . . .'.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: You have conflated wifi, tcp, http, and the socket api so that I'm not sure what you are asking. You could play around with any number of [http-related modules in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html), however on the client-side I think most people prefer to use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused on what TCP and HTTP is. TCP is part of layer 4 of the OSI model. HTTP is layer 7 of the OSI model.

Http is a protocol/standard used to exchange data with another Http enabled endpoint. Http is built on top of TCP. Http uses TCP to send data. The server has a TCP socket listening for data and once it receives data it then passes it along to another "process/program/line of code" to then parse that data using Http standards.

If you are wanting to use http to send/receive data you will need a web framework like Flask, Django or Starlette. They are Http servers with added features to allow you to code what you want to do with the data rather than handling the lower level stuff of parsing the http data being sent over TCP.

Http is a HUGE protocol/standard. If you try to do the parsing from scratch it is a big project to undertake.